# Possible way to do block synchronization in CUDA kernels

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I am recently working on a code that requires a initialization of a piece of global memory before each kernel launch, which will be modified later in the same kernel. I used to do a `cudaMemset` before each kernel launch. But the overhead cannot be neglected when I need to call this kernel for thousands of times. So I finally come up with this idea which is to use global memory to judge if all initialization work has been done. But I soon found that when some threads within the active blocks are doing the loop, the following blocks will not keep launching, which results in a dead loop.

```
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (i < (n + n)) {
        data[i] = 0;
}//working.
__syncthreads();//sync
if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        atomicAdd((unsigned *)&flag, 1);//voting    
        while (flag < gridDim.x); //waiting
    }
}
__syncthreads();
//do something with data
```

So is there a way to manually put the current blocks to sleep and keep the kernels launching? Or is there better solution for my initialization problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found out, you should not attempt block synchronization in CUDA - this will prevent later blocks from launching (because earlier blocks do not give up their resources) and deadlocks at the synchronization point.

Instead of trying to put blocks to sleep until their work is ready, try to *move the work to a block that happens to be currently running*. The [Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) has a [worked example at the end of it's memory fence section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) for doing some extra work in the last block of a kernel. You could use this to prepare the global memory variables for the next block.

The benefit of not having to perform an extra cudaMemcpy() or an additional kernel launch however needs to be weighed against the extra atomic memory access per block and synchronization within each block. So with increasing number of blocks per grid at some point it is cheaper to just perform the extra cudaMemcpy().